# Xaml, System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting - Display X-Axis label as seconds instead of Time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

We collect data from a gyroscope at a variable sampling frequency from 50 Hz to 800 Hz. The Y-Axis values are doubles, the X-Axis values are `DateTime` values converted from OADate. Currently the chart displays a timestamp (e.g. 8:00:32 am, 8:00:33 am) on the X-Axis. I've also tried accumulating the periods in a `TimeSpan`, but the chart creates a label for each sample (of which there are thousands) which causes the X-Axis labels to be unreadable. I would like the X-Axis to display the elapsed duration in seconds instead of a time (e.g. 0,1,2,3...). How do I do that programmatically?

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using MathNet.Numerics.Data.Text;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

public class BlahBlah
{
        private const int REC_NUM = 0;
        private const int DATE = 1;
        private const int X_FIELD = 2;

        private void CreateData(Dictionary<string, Series> dictionary, IEnumerable<Vector<double>> record)
        {
            dictionary.Clear();
            List<Tuple<DateTime, double>> tX = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();

            //Take the first record and perfrom some initialization...
            var firstRecord = record.First();

            long count = 0;
            DateTime last = DateTime.FromOADate(firstRecord[DATE]);
            DateTime current;
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0);
            //Now loop through all the records
            foreach (var v in record)
            {
                double dx = 0;

                dx = v[X_FIELD]);

                current = DateTime.FromOADate(v[DATE]);
                ts = ts +  current.Subtract(last);

                //My attempt at using timespan
                //tX.Add(new Tuple<TimeSpan, double>(ts, lx));

                tX.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(DateTime.FromOADate(v[DATE]), dx));
                last = current;
                count++;
            }

            Color cs = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#4FD7DA");

            Style style = new Style();

            style = new Style(typeof(Control));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(cs)));
            //Turn off datapoints by setting the style to null
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.TemplateProperty, null));

            dictionary.Add("x", new LineSeries() {
                Name = "x",
                ItemsSource = tX,
                IndependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Item1"),
                DependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Item2"),
                Title = "X Axis",
                DataPointStyle = style

            });
        }
    }

...

chart1.Series.Add(dictionary["x"]);
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code to build the data?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've added a contrived version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right with accumulating the `TimeSpan` values, but instead of using TimeSpan/DateTime values itself you can use [Seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.seconds?view=netframework-4.8) value of TimeSpan. And change your `ItemSource` to

```
List<Tuple<int, double>> tX = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();
```

If you want to display the elapsed duration in seconds instead of a time (e.g. 0,1,2,3...), during the build of data you should remember the first `DateTime` value (0 point), than subtract it from the `DateTime` of next sample and use the `Seconds` or `TotalSeconds` (if there are a thousands samples) of resulting `TimeSpan` as elapsed seconds value

Comment: Ah, ha! Using a datatype of double and Timespan.TotalSeconds was the solution! ```tX.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(ts.TotalSeconds, dx));```